# how can i make a variable every day in python

Tags: python, windows-7-x64, python-3.8

i want to make a diary so every day it makes a variable with a input() statement. i would like to name the variable to be named eg.day_06_02_2021 and there will be a new variable every day with the correct date. Any way i can do it?

Comment: Short answer: don't. Use a dict.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Also, note that the tag windows-7-x64 states that it is to be used for questions specific to this version of Windows, so it's irrelevant on almost any Python question. The same applies to the python-3.8 tag.